# pass props into another component in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to pass   `props.userId` to another component and `console.log` it in `PersonalDetail`  component. I am not able to pass it.
It says undefined   `props.userId`  has values of integers

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  var id = props.userId;
  this.state = { isClose: false, userid1: { id } };
}
```

```
 <PersonalDetail userid1={this.state.userid1} />
```

`persoalnal.js`

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function PersonalDetail(props) {

  var userid = props.userid1;
  console.log(props.userid1);


  return (
    <>
    <h1>personal details</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full code for PersonalDetails component and the component you are using PersonalDetails in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the upper component props userId's value.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  console.log(props.userId);
  this.state = {
    isClose: false,
    userid1: { id: props.userId },
  };
}


<PersonalDetail userid1={this.state.userid1.id} />
```